# Legitimate reasons for Cherem

Tags: halacha, taamei-mitzvot-reasons, yoreh-deah, cherem, nidui-ostracism

According to Halacha, one is eligible for Cherem themselves if they  put someone else in Cherem for an illegitimate reason. My question is, what constitutes a legitimate  reason for Cherem and what constitutes an illegitimate reason?

Comment: A cherem for a cherem puts the whole world in cherem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Yoreh Deah 334:43](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.334.43?lang=bi) lists 24 instances of when to impose a cherem and is also brought down in [Mishneh Torah, Hilchos Talmud Torah 6:14](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Torah_Study.6.14?lang=bi)

List as follows:

1. A person who disgraces a sage, even after his passing.
2. A person who embarrasses a messenger of a court
3. A person who calls a colleague a slave
4. A person who was ordered [to appear before] a court at a specific time and did not come
5. A person who treats even one point of Rabbinic law with disrespect; needless to say, this applies regarding [matters of] Torah law
6. A person who refuses to comply with the decisions [rendered by a court] is placed under ban until he complies
7. A person who possesses an entity that can cause damage - e.g., a dangerous dog or a faulty ladder - is placed under ban until he removes that entity
8. A person who sells land to a gentile is placed under ban until he accepts responsibility for any damages which the gentile may cause his Jewish neighbour
9. A person who testifies against a Jewish colleague in a secular court and causes money which Torah law would not [require him to pay] to be expropriated from him is placed under ban until he repays [that amount]
10. A butcher who is a priest and does not separate the priestly gifts and give them to another priest is placed under ban until he gives them.
11. A person who violates the sanctity of the second day of the festivals in the Diaspora, even though [their observance] is only a custom

l2) A person who performs work on Pesach eve after noon

13. A person who takes G-d's name in vain or takes an oath casually
14. A person who causes the many to desecrate God's name
15. A person who causes the many to eat sacrificial food outside [its proper place]
16. A person who calculates the years [and declares a leap year] or fixes the day of the new month in the Diaspora
17. A person who causes the blind [ - i.e., the morally unaware - ] to stumble
18. A person who prevents the many from performing a mitzvah
19. A butcher who sold non-kosher meat
20. A butcher who does not inspect his knife in the presence of a sage
21. A person who intentionally causes himself to have an erection
22. A person who divorced his wife, and then entered into a partnership or business dealing with her which requires them to come into contact. When they come to court, they are placed under ban
23. A sage whose reputation is unsavory
24. A person who places a person under ban when the latter does not deserve [such punishment]